# What social aggregators are complete?

Tags: microeconomics, theory, choice-theory, social-choice

I am reading [Eliaz (2004](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00355-003-0291-1)) for a general treatment of social-choice impossibilities. I am confused by the fact that it seems that we should get completeness even in situations where we should not have it.

Some terminology: let $V$ be a set of $n \geq 2$ voters and $X$ a set of 3 or more alternatives. Let $P$ be the set of all linear orderings on $X$, and let $\succ$ be a typical element of $P$. Let $R$ be the set of all binary relations on $X$. A **social aggregator** is a function $F: P \to R$. Properties of social aggregators may include:

- **C**ompleteness: for all $(a,b) \in X^2, a R b \lor b R a$
- **B**est **A**lternative: there is some $a \in X: a R b $ for all $b$
- **Par**eto: if $a \succ_i b$ for all $i \in V$, then $b \lnot R a$
- **P**reference **R**eversal: for all $\succ, \succ' \in P$, if $a F(\succ) b$ and $a \lnot F(\succ') b$, then for some $i \in V$, $a \succ b$ and $b \succ' a$.

I now want to show the following:

**Claim.** Suppose $F$ satisfies **BA**, **Par**, **PR**. Then $F$ satisfies **C**.

*Proof*. Consider some profile $\succ$ where for all $i \in N$, $a \succ c$ and $b \succ c$ for all $c \in X \setminus \{a,b\}$ for some $a \neq b$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ are the two top alternatives for all voters). By Pareto, $c \lnot F(\succ) a,b$. By best alternative, then $a F(\succ) b$ or $b F(\succ) a$. WLOG, suppose $a F(\succ) b$. Then consider any profile $\succ'$ such that for all $i$, $a \succ_i b \iff a \succ'_i b$. By preference reversal, $a F(\succ') b$. Because we have not placed any restriction on $\{i \mid a \succ_i b\}$, and $(a,b)$ was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that $F$ satisfies completeness. QED.

Is there a mistake? If not, doesn't Eliaz's results (including those connecting PR to monotonicity) imply that a monotonic social choice function (the subject of Gibbard-Statterthwaite's theorem) must be complete?

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. But your definitions of BA and PR differ from the ones used by Eliaz.

Comment: I see how the difference in my definition of PR might change the result, but the difference in the definition of BA should be immaterial, no?

Comment: I think so too, apart from the resulting relation possibly not being reflexive.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking at Proposition 1 in Eliaz. Let PR' be preference reversal as defined by him (weaker than my definition). I'm having trouble seeing if my definition of PR also fits this result, since for $F : P \to R_0 =  \{(a,b) \mid b \in X \} \subset R$, it seems that PR  and PR' are equivalent: if $a R_0 b$, then $b \lnot R_0 a$ (assuming $a \neq b$), and thus PR and PR' collapse, no? So don't we still get completeness of $R_0$? (Assume reflexivity for now).

Comment: Your definition of preference reversal differs from the one of ELiaz in more than one way. The one of Eliaz says that if $a$ is socially strictly preferred to $b$ in one profile and $b$ socially weakly preferred to $a$ in the second profile, then someone must prefer $a$ to $b$ in the former profile who prefers $b$ to $a$ in the latter profile. Your definition says that if $a$ is socially weakly preferred to $b$ in one profile but not in another profile, then someone must prefer $a$ to $b$ in the former profile who prefers $b$ to $a$ in the latter profile. So the definition differs in two ways

Comment: Now, it is true that every weak preference between two different alternatives is a strict preference in $R_0$. But $a$ not being preferred to $b$ in $R_0$ does not mean that $b$ is preferred to $a$ in $R_0$.

Comment: I see the difference better now, thanks. So my definition is not necessarily stronger, right? (Although it yields completeness, which rules out social choice functions, and that's a bit too strong). I'm going to think more about under what conditions PR and PR' are equivalent. You are always extremely helpful!